# Android FileOutputStream Seems to Fail

Tags: java, android, file, sockets

I am trying to transfer a video file from an RPi hotspot to my a directory on my phone over WiFi. I have been able to successfully create a folder in my storage, connect with the RPi server, and receive data. However, the file that appears after being written isn't correct. In fact, when I try to open it, it just opens a separate, unrelated app on my phone. Very weird!

Here is the code in question:

```
 try {
            BufferedInputStream myBis = new BufferedInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream());
            DataInputStream myDis = new DataInputStream(myBis);

            byte[] videoBuffer = new byte[4096*2];
            int i = 0;

            while (mySocket.getInputStream().read(videoBuffer) != -1) {
                Log.d(debugStr, "while loop");
                videoBuffer[videoBuffer.length-1-i] = myDis.readByte();
                Log.d(debugStr, Arrays.toString(videoBuffer));
                i++;
            }

            Log.d(debugStr, "done with while loop");
            // create a File object for the parent directory

            File testDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator, "recordFolder");
            Log.d(debugStr, "path made?");
            if(!testDirectory.exists()){
                testDirectory.mkdirs();
            }
            Log.d(debugStr, "directory made");
            // create a File object for the output file
            File outputFile = new File(testDirectory.getPath(), "recording1");

            Log.d(debugStr, "outputfile made");
            // now attach the OutputStream to the file object, i

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            Log.d(debugStr, "write to file object made");


            fileOutputStream.write(videoBuffer);
            Log.d(debugStr, "video written");
            fileOutputStream.close();

            Log.d(debugStr, "done");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The video is initially in .h264 format and is being sent as a byte array. The file is 10MB in size. In my while loop, I print out the value of the array as a string, and it prints a lot of data. Enough data for me to suspect that all the data is being sent. When I navigate to the folder it should be in, there is a file with the name I gave it, "recording1", but it is only 8KB in size.

Any ideas on what is going on? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

> Android `FileOutputStream` seems to fail

No it doesn't. Your code seems to fail. That's because your code makes no sense. You're throwing away large chunks of data, more or less accumulating only 1 out of every 8192 bytes; you're using both buffered and unbuffered reads; you're limiting the input to 8192 bytes; and you're never closing the input. And if the input is larger than 8192*8193 you can get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Throw it all away and use this:

```
try {
        File testDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator, "recordFolder");
        if(!testDirectory.exists()){
            testDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
        File outputFile = new File(testDirectory, "recording1");
        try (OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream())) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or more, whatever you like > 0
            int count;
            // Canonical Java copy loop
            while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: If you want to show how things should be done, you should also show good resource handling by using try-with-resources, or at least try-finally.

Comment: Why buffer `InputStream`, but not `OutputStream`? If anything, it should be the other way around, given that socket `InputStream` may return less data than buffer size, whether buffered or not.

Comment: @Andreas Don't be inhibited from posting your own answer, in which you should address the actual issue, not side-issues like that.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried that code and am now receiving a file that is around 18 MB which is much closer to what I expect. However, when I try to open the file, it still opens another random app. Is there some sort of specification I need to make so that my phone realizes its a video file?

Comment: You probably need to provide an appropriate extension in the filename.

Comment: testDir.mkdirs() made the different for me. I assumed the directory exists. Thanks